# why is the httphandler not running

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, httphandler, iis-express

I have written an httpHandler for an ASP.NET MVC4 site that generates an an image.  The `ProcessRequest` function is not being called.  Any thoughts on why?

MVC4, IIS Express, Windows 8 Pro

**Web.config > system.webServer**

```
 <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="TextImage" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <add name="TextImage" path="textimage/*.png" verb="*" resourceType="Unspecified" type="MultiStepUI.TextImageHandler, MultiStepUI_MOBETTER" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

**usage**

```
<img src="/textimage/step1.png?q=Step 1&c=404040&w=30&h=250&z=12" />
```

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/post/3416052.aspx

Comment: well, thank you tmack for that link explaining what a httphandler is.  Unfortunately it has absolutely nothing to do with my question.

Comment: yyyyyyep. note to self, stop skimming.

Comment: heh.  It *was* a good read though.  Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer can be found on the web if one just knows what to look for.

MVC routing engine tries to map all requests to a controller - which is not what we want in this case.  In addition to registering the handler in Web.config we need to tell the MVC route engine to ignore the httpHandler `path` so that the ASP.NET engine can handle its routing.

I've chosen to use the [example from Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/14/make-routing-ignore-requests-for-a-file-extension.aspx)

**To combat link rot this is an excerpt from the article**

> By default, ASP.NET Routing ignores requests for files that do not
>   exist on disk. I explained the reason for this in a previous post on
>   upcoming routing changes. Long story short, we didn’t want routing to
>   attempt to route requests for static files such as images.
>   Unfortunately, this caused us a headache when we remembered that many
>   features of ASP.NET make requests for .axd files which do not exist on
>   disk.
>
> To fix this, we included a new extension method on
>   RouteCollection, IgnoreRoute, that creates a Route mapped to the
>   StopRoutingHandler route handler (class that implements
>   IRouteHandler). Effectively, any request that matches an “ignore
>   route” will be ignored by routing and normal ASP.NET handling will
>   occur based on existing http handler mappings. Hence in our default
>   template, you’ll notice we have the following route defined.
>
> routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
>
> This handles the
>   standard .axd requests. However, there are other cases where you might
>   have requests for files that don’t exist on disk. For example, if you
>   register an HTTP Handler directly to a type that implements
>   IHttpHandler. Not to mention requests for favicon.ico that the browser
>   makes automatically. *ASP.NET Routing attempts to route these requests
>   to a controller.* One solution to this is to add an appropriate ignore
>   route to indicate that routing should ignore these requests.
>   Unfortunately, we can’t do something like this:
>
> {*path}.aspx/{*pathinfo}
>
> *We only allow one catch-all route and it must
>   happen at the end of the URL*. However, you can take the following
>   approach. In this example, I added the following two routes.
>
> routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allaspx}", new {allaspx=@".*\.aspx(/.*)?"});
>   routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new {favicon=@"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?"});
>
> What I’m doing here is a
>   technique Eilon showed me which is to map all URLs to these routes,
>   but then restrict which routes to ignore via the constraints
>   dictionary. So in this case, these routes will match (and thus ignore)
>   all requests for favicon.ico (no matter which directory) as well as
>   requests for a .aspx file. Since we told routing to ignore these
>   requests, normal ASP.NET processing of these requests will occur.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. The article had this correction "By default, ASP.NET Routing ignores requests for files that do exist on disk."

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is correct, but the article has been edited from the excerpt placed here. The ignore statements should read:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allaspx}", new {allaspx=@".*\.aspx(/.*)?"});
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new {favicon=@"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?"});
```

Note the '*' in the {*allaspx} and {*favicon} strings that is missing in the original.
I could not get it to work until I followed the link and followed the example in the updated article.

Comment: Frank,  Thank you for pointing this out.  There was no edit to the article.  I didn't catch it, but the SO markdown renderer thought the `*`s in the block quote were formatting, not content.  I've escaped the proper symbols and now the content of the block quote should match what was intended - even though now the "actual" content behind the block quote is different from what is rendered... if that makes any sense.