# Routing a .GIF one way, the rest of the MVC 4 site another

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-routing

I've been trawling through 1000s of questions and blogs and still don't fully understand dam routing!

Along the lines of [Scott Hanselman's blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsDynamicImageGenerationASPNETControllersRoutingIHttpHandlersAndRunAllManagedModulesForAllRequests.aspx) I am trying to route a certain call to a .GIF to a custom HttpHandler while the rest of the MVC4 site behaves normally. I'm 90% of the way there.

So in the my RouteConfig I have

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.Add("AnalyticsRoute", new Route("analytics/a.gif", new AnalyticsRouteHandler()));
    routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
    routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
}
```

and in my web.config I have

```
<handlers>
  ...
  <add name="analytics" verb="*" path="analytics/a.gif" type="Lms.Analytics.AnalyticsHandler, Lms.Analytics" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</handlers>
```

Now this way, http://mysite.com/analytics/a.gif routes correctly and all is happy, however all my ActionLinks are resolving as http://mysite.com/analytics/a.gif?action=Index&controller=Category

If I reverse the order in the RouteConfig i.e.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
    routes.Add("AnalyticsRoute", new Route("analytics/a.gif", new AnalyticsRouteHandler()));
    routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
}
```

All the links resolve just fine, but a call to http://mysite.com/analytics/a.gif results in a 404 error?

I must be doing something stupid and just can't see it?!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After finally coming across a similar post, I cracked it. The post was [why is the httphandler not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261346/why-is-the-httphandler-not-running)

You need to ignore the path to the file you want the HttpHandler to handle

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("analytics/a.gif");
        routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
        routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
    }
```

The problem was when I added the web.config and removed the Route.Add I got a 404. I guess the Routing engine was over ruling the Handler.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to create your own custom `Route` class.

In this class you must override the `GetVirtualPath` method ([on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routebase.getvirtualpath.aspx)), which will examine the route data, and generate the right Url. Implement it so that it returns `null` if your special Url it's not in the provided `RequestContext`.

What is going on now in your app is that you're using the standard `Route` class which treat the controller and action in the `RouteValue` dictionary as overflow paramters, so they're added to the created url.

When you add the route to the route collection use your custom class instead of the default `Route` class.

More explanation: when you use any method like `Url.Action` to create a Url, `RouteCollection.GetVirtualPath` is called. And this method calls the `GetVirtualPath` of every registered `Route`, until one of them returns a value different from null (the Url string). 
As you're not providing your own `Route` class, the "standard" `Route` class is being used, and returning the undesired Url. If you create your custom `Route` class with you own `GetVirtualPath` implementation you'll return the desired Url.

Comment: Hmm, this may have worked too, but wasn't a path I wanted to pursue. I was sure it could be handled in the HttpHandlers. Sorry I didn't try it and solved it another way.

Comment: how did you solve it? You should share your solution so does we all can see it, and mark it as correct (what you can do after 2 days, I think).

Answer (score 0):

According to Hanselman's article, you *don't* want to add a route for your image, you just want to set up the handler in your `web.config`. Have you tried removing your `AnalyticsRoute` and see if it works? You may also need to add an ignore route to keep MVC from trying to handle the request.

I haven't used it, but I've heard [RouteMagic](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/30/introducing-routemagic.aspx), written by Phil Haack, is great at troubleshooting route issues.

Comment: That's not what I got from Hasselmans article, I got that you could get around using runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false". Quote: "Remember that HttpHandlers are targeted to a specific path, file or wildcard and HttpModules are always watching. Why not use an HttpHandler directly and plug it in at the web.config level and set runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false"?" He didn't mention anywhere what to do with the Route.Add. I did try and remove it but only got 404's. THanks anyhow.